# UX Patterns for Horizontal Scrolling wide tables

Tags: tables, scrolling

I'm working on a web app that functions more or less like a kanban with rows extending off-screen to the bottom and columns extending offscreen to the right.  The solution requested is to add a "scrubber" to the top of the table above the columns in order indicate to users that there are additional columns to the right off screen and it would have the functionality to allow users to drag a controller to move columns to left or right to make the ones off-screen visible.  Their concern is that users won't understand how many columns there are that are off screen, but I'm concerned a scrubber at the top (instead of at the bottom) may be overkill when a traditional horizontal scroll bar would suffice.  Are there any other design patterns for navigating wide kanban tables (or gantt charts) that might work here?

Comment: Welcome to the site @Brooklynne. I understand that you are concerned about the 'discoverability' of more columns to the right. If this is a tool that is frequently used, I would guess that users will quickly learn that there might be more columns to the right. If you are still concerned you could consider using a pattern from image carousels in which content bleeds off the site to signal that there is more to discover.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend only showing the scrollbar on hover and having sticky columns that allow the user to still see which rows are relevant.

Adding a shadow to the sticky column will give the impression that the columns are scrolling beneath.

I think having the scrollbar at the bottom is fine as long as the table is not taller than the window. If it is taller then maybe also consider making the table scrollable vertically.

example:

[image]

Comment: The table will be tall and wide, so it will need to scroll horizontally as well as vertically.  The example above is what I proposed but the client feels that even with the horizontal scrollbar it's not obvious enough that there are more columns to the right.

Comment: You could add options to allow the user to order the columns so that they can position the most important ones to the start. 

You could also set the column widths to make sure the last visible column is only 50% visible so users can see that more content is available.